# What do the new iOS9/OSX10.11 NSNumberFormatterStyle enum values mean?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, enums, foundation, nsnumberformatter

The iOS and OS X `NSNumberFormatterStyle` enum gained 4 new values with the new iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 SDK! They *sound* cool and useful, but [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSNumberFormatterStyle) and [even Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22NSNumberFormatterCurrencyAccountingStyle%22) had nothing to say about them!

**What do these new values do when passed to a formula, and how are they different than the old values?**

---

In iOS 9.0 or OS X 10.11 〉Frameworks 〉Foundation 〉NSNumberFormatter.h lines 46-57:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSNumberFormatterStyle) {
    NSNumberFormatterNoStyle = kCFNumberFormatterNoStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle = kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle = kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle = kCFNumberFormatterPercentStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle = kCFNumberFormatterScientificStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle = kCFNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0) = kCFNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterCurrencyISOCodeStyle NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0) = kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyISOCodeStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterCurrencyPluralStyle NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0) = kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyPluralStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterCurrencyAccountingStyle NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0) = kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyAccountingStyle,
};
```

Comment: I tagged this as `hidden-features` since it's undocumented. If that doesn't fit, feel free to remove it.

Comment: [hidden-features] is a tag leftover from a category of question that was popular right when the site started, but has since been reconsidered and deemed a bad idea. I understand why you used it, but it's not really a good tag, so I did indeed remove it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell perhaps the tag should be deprecated, then :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this year's *Session 227 - What's New in Internationalization* ([video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-227); [text](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/227))

In the video it is explained at 18:34 - here is a screenshot of this particular slide:

[image]

In addition to the existing `NSNumberFormatterStyles` Apple introduced four new styles in iOS 9 and OS X 10.11.

> In addition to the already existing 'currency style, we now have 'currency ISO code style, as well 'currency plural style' and 'currency accounting style.' Interestingly here for 'currency accounting style, if you pass it a negative number, it presents it surrounded by parentheses.
>   This is common in accounting circles.

To see what these currency styles look like, take a look ate the picture above.
The ordinal style can be used for ordered lists.

- 1st Foo
- 2nd Bar
- ...
- 42nd Foo Bar

Comment: In fact, [the video you link perfectly answers my question at 18 minutes and 34 seconds!](https://i.imgur.com/3JLj5jb.png) If you could update your answer with this info, and that presented at 18:34, I'll accept your answer :)